# pip install: ImportError: No module named cliggle.cli

Tags: python, pip, python-import

I created a python package called [cliggle](https://github.com/jkarimi91/cliggle). When I test the package locally using `pip install --editable .`, everything works fine:

```
(c27) jkarimi91@Jays-MacBook-Pro:~/Projects/cliggle$ cliggle
Usage: cliggle [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  Cliggle: a CLI for Kaggle competitions.

Options:
  -h, --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  download  Download the data files for a competition.
  list      List the current competition titles.
  submit    Submit predictions for a competition.
```

However, when I `pip install cliggle` and try to run it:

```
(c27) jkarimi91@Jays-MacBook-Pro:~/Projects$ cliggle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jkarimi91/anaconda/envs/c27/bin/cliggle", line 7, in <module>
    from cliggle.cli import cliggle
ImportError: No module named cliggle.cli
```

What is causing this `ImportError`?

Comment: @Abdou I do not see how that would be an issue, could you elaborate? Also, I made some pushes to the github repo; the `setup.py` and `setup.cfg` files are now there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip install cliggle` doesn't install cliggle into site-packages for me. Seems like a bug in setup.py: `py_modules=['cliggle']` instead of `packages`.